# When viewing form from InfoPath 2013 to Sharepoint 2010. This form template is not enabled for viewing in the browser

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am getting the error `This form template is not enabled for viewing in the browser.` when I publish my InfoPath 2013 to my Sharepoint 2010.

Steps I have already followed:

- Site Collection Features has "Enterprise Features enabled"
- Site Features also has "Enterprise Features" enabled
- Forms Library has "View as Web Page" enabled in advance settings
- Infopath Forms Service has Render and User Browser Compatible Forms enabled
- Set Compatibility mode in InfoPath to Web Browser Form 2010

I have made a blank form just to test if it will publish, but I am receiving the same error.

Concerns:
Does it have to do with anything with publishing from InfoPath 2013 to Sharepoint 2010?

Please let me know if there is any confusion in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did this process used to work and now it has stopped working?  Have you successfully published and used a form with this method?

A user here reported this same error yesterday, and it is one I've never seen before.  Apparently, our company's updates of Microsoft patches installed a portion of Office 2010 on this person's system.  Once this was uninstalled, InfoPath returned to working as normal.

(We also publish InfoPath 2010-compatible forms from systems running Office 2013.)

This may not be related at all to your problem, but since we saw this symptom just yesterday, I figured it might help.

Paul